# Repeating SQL insert statement in loop till id has certain value?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include ("db.php");

$id2 = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM osalejad;";
$id = $conn->query($id2);
if (id<= 8){
    while($id<= 7) {
        $min = 1;
        $max = 20;
        $suvanumber = rand($min, $max);
        $bar = (string) $suvanumber;
        $prii= "vaba2" . $bar;

        $sql="INSERT INTO osalejad (name) VALUES ('$prii')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo '8 osalejat on juba kirjas';
}

?>
```

I have a question, i want to  insert data into MYSQl table, word with a random number, but problem is, it never work as it should - if i have 3 records in name column, then till, it adds 8 more records, instead of 5 records. Is something outside of scope atm?

I will use the DB in this code.

```
<?php


include("db.php");  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `osalejad`;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$var = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $var[] = $row["name"];
    }
} else {
   /// echo "0 results";
}


//shuffle the array, and encode into json.
shuffle($var);
$brack=json_encode($var);
$testbrack= json_encode(array_chunk($var,2));


$final = '{';
$final .= '"teams":';
$final .= $testbrack;
$final .= ',"results":[[[[0,0],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null]]]]}';
//updating last tournament bracket.
$sql1 = "UPDATE lan_brackets SET json='$final' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 1;";

$roundOne=$conn->query($sql1);


?>
```

Comment: Your issue is that you have to go back and understand how query execution works. Look at this line you use: `$id = $conn->query($id2);`. Here `$id` will receive a _result handler_ for further usage, and _not_ the result (`MAX(id)`) you are interested in.

Comment: is this your real code? eg : if (id<= 8){

Comment: If `$id` is e.g. `5`, then your `while($id<=7)`-loop will loop forever. The value of `$id` isn't changed in the loop, so the expression is always true.

Comment: So, i should use for loop, like i=Max(id); i<=8; i++ ? 
Actually, later i plan to make a function, with parameter how many  names are placed into table - like 4-8-16-32 and so after. But first i would like to get this code working.

Comment: Is your ID column auto-incrementing? Then yes. Sounds reasonable. Or put the `select max(id)...` _into_ the loop or use `select last_insert_id()` [(docs)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in the loop. This is the best because the `for` loop might fail if someone else (other DB connection) inserts simultaneously.

Comment: Why i need it, i need  certain amounts of names into array - but i didnt got it with array_push  in a loop working.

Comment: So you don't need MySQL here at all? (serious question) You just use it because you can't figure out how `array_push` in pure PHP works?